# Quickbooks Pro Developer with Enterprise User

Tags: sdk, desktop, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have Quickbooks Pro. My customer is planning to purchase Enterprise.  I have code that uses the SDK to add invoices.  Can I continue to develop/test with Pro and then deploy to an Enterprise user.  Will I need to upgrade my Pro edition to Enterprise.

Comment: Usually the more advanced versions of a software include the features of the less advanced but why not just ask their support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK for QuickBooks is the same for Pro, Premier, and Enterprise, however there may be features that are not available in the Pro version that are available in the higher tier products. For example, Pro does not have Inventory Assemblies.

You can query for some functionality in the file that you are connected to by using the IPreferencesQuery, as it's also possible that a feature is available, but not enabled (i.e. Pro supports regular Inventory items, but the user may not have the feature turned on).

You may also want to check for error 1030 when performing requests as this typically indicates that the request is not supported in the year/edition of QuickBooks that you are connected to.